Confusion about one pushforward calculation on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$
Let $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the standard sphere and let
$$
F \colon \{ (p, r, X) \colon \ p \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}, \ r > 0, \ X \in T_p \mathbb{S}^{n-1}, \ |X| = 1\}
\to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}
$$
be the following map:
$$
F ( p, r, X ) = \exp_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} ( p, r X ) = p \, \cos r + X \, \sin r.
$$
I want to calculate the pushforward
$
F_* \frac{\partial}{\partial r}.
$
Using the fact that $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$, I take standard coordinates $x^1, \ldots, x^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and write
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_* \frac{\partial}{\partial r}
& = \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \, x^l \Big( p \, \cos r + X \, \sin r \Big) \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}
\\[3pt]
& = \Big( - x^l ( p ) \, \sin r + x^l ( X ) \, \cos r \Big) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}
\\[3pt]
& = -p \, \sin r + X \, \cos r.
\end{aligned}
$$
The resulting vector is not tangent to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ because $p$ isn't. What did I do wrong?

Your calculation is correct and results in a tangent vector at the appropriate base point. In more detail:
First let $M:= \{ (p, r, X) \colon \ p \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}, \ r > 0, \ X \in T_p \mathbb{S}^{n-1}, \ |X| = 1\}$ for ease of notation. For each point $q:=(p,r,X) \in M$ the pushforward of $\frac {\partial}{\partial r} \in T_qM$ by $F$ defines a tangent vector $F_*\frac {\partial}{\partial r} \in T_{F(q)}\mathbb S^{n-1}$. To check your expression actually gives a tangent vector, you must check that the vector $-p \sin r + X \cos r$ is in the tangent space at $F(p,r,X)$.
By the characterization of the tangent space of the sphere, this simply means checking that the vector $-p \sin r + X \cos r$ is orthogonal to $F(p,r,X) = p \cos r + X \sin r$. Using the fact that $X \perp p$ and $|X| = |p| = 1$ we find that
$$\langle -p \sin r + X \cos r,p \cos r + X \sin r\rangle = \sin r \cos r \big( \langle X, X\rangle - \langle p, p\rangle \big) = \sin r \cos r \big( 1 - 1\big) = 0$$
so $p \sin r + X \cos r$ lies in the tangent space at $ p \cos r + X \sin r$ (which is different from the tangent space at $p$).

Thank you very much, it was a very stupid mistake indeed...
